# Parent Child Relationships

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssas, powerpivot

This regarding handling parent child relationships in PowerPivot. I am facing a situation where the "PATH" dax function is giving me trouble with the set of data provided to the function.

My data set has a parent column and a column with the child ids. Roots of the hierarchies do not have a corresponding row in the child ids column. Due to this reason PowerPivot gives me the following error when the "PATH" function is applied:

"Calculation error in column 'CS_Comp'[]: The value '10' in 'CS_Comp'[ParentCol] must also exist in 'CS_Comp'[ChildCol].  Please add the missing data and try again."

Answer (score 1):

can you post an example of your data? Why do you need a Parent and a ChildID. Normally you would need ID and ParentID only

[image]